# Efficient way to implement frequent cron job in production environment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, cron

I am working on deploying a service in production environment (using AWS), where the task is to:

- Update some parameters at an regular interval (every minute)
- API to fetch these params so that it can be integrated with some other service.

For a workaround for this i have deployed a docker image and exposed two api's, one for updating the parameters and another one for fetching those updated params. The update api i am calling every minute using AWS lambda.

This setup is working fine but is there any other way this problem can be solved more elegantly?

Comment: The question when you talk about production will be: is it properly secure & how durable the current solutions are? ideally you will first look for manage service offered by AWS to leverage their durability & high availability landscape, for the security are you storing those values encrypted at rest & in transit? you can look to services like s3 with encryption can be a good option and service like aws secret manager and api gateway + lambda instead of docker image if it's on EC2.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to **store the parameters in Amazon S3**.

Various systems can simply retrieve the object from S3 to get the parameters. Updating would imply involve replacing the object. Security can be provided to limit the ability to read & update the object. It's also very low-cost.

Alternatively, there is [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html), which is made for this type of thing. Again, access can be tightly controlled.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you have a lambda cron that uses an event trigger every 'dt'.
These examples describes the core of this idea:

[Cron job with serverless](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/ba1c788fa93e980b4b8ed464006994064a09bc1e/aws-python-scheduled-cron)

[Get weather data](https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/ac5c75e72aebc35aff9990038f4711dab2be0395/aws-node-scheduled-weather/handler.js)

It would be a good investment to use serverless if you aren't already.

Inside the cron job lambda handler, you could then do a 'GET' to retrieve your data and upload it as a record in DynamoDB.